# Como gerar números aleatórios sem que haja reperição em Java?

Tags: java, loop, random, int, números-aleatórios

Algo similar ao código abaixo. Números no intervalo do Random que não se repitam

```
public void sorteiaCartelaB() {
        for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++) {
            b[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 60 + 1);
            for (int j=0; j<b.length; j++)
                if (b[i] == b[j] && i != j)
                    b[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 60 + 1);
                else 
                    continue;
        }
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040001/creating-random-numbers-with-no-duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma outra possibilidade de implementar:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
class Main {
  private static Scanner scanner;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Digite o tamanho da lista");
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int quantidade = scanner.nextInt();
    List<Integer> listadistintos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int sorteio;
    do {
      boolean adicionarLista = true;
      sorteio = (int) (Math.random() * 100);  //ajustar valores aqui
      for (int i : listadistintos){
        if (i == sorteio) {
          adicionarLista = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (adicionarLista) { listadistintos.add(sorteio); }
    } while (listadistintos.size() < quantidade);
    //System.out.println("Lista de números distintos");
    //for (int x : listadistintos) {
    //  System.out.println(x);
    //}
  }
}
```

Uma coisa para ter cuidado é que dependendo dos parâmetros que passar, é possível gerar um loop infinito.

Ex:
Se eu mudar os parâmetros para `Math.random() * 5)`

E desejo gerar uma lista com 6 posições. A condição de saída do laço `do` nunca será alcançada.

Pois só existe a possibilidade de ser sorteado 5 números distintos.

```
0 , 1 , 2, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma possibilidade:

```
quantidade = ???;
Set<Integer> numeros = new HashSet<>();
Random rnd = new Random(semente);
while (numeros.size() < quantidade) {
    numeros.add(rnd.nextInt(60) + 1);
}
```